# Can py2exe make a "real win32 exe"? Other words,is the exe built in machine-code?

Tags: python, performance, py2exe

i'm trying to improve the excuting speed of my python program through py2exe…but i'm not sure if it works.Thanks~!

Comment: py2exe basically creates a self-executing archive containing python. It doesn't create pure machine code

Comment: why are you trying to improve speed in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To improve speed, try [cython](http://cython.org/) instead. py2exe just wraps an exe around the python so it makes no difference.